# Some questions in book of Frisch&Kolmogorov at Chapter 6

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

[image]

[image: Frisch&Kolmogorov's book at CH6]

1. i'm not native speak, what does the above sentence meaning? —— whether the sentence “which are small compared to the integral scale” refers to increments $\ell$ only or refers to increments $\ell$ & displacements $ρ$ both？
2. In my understanding, if a turbulence is homogeneous at small scales，then it just needs one of ρ and *l* is small to integral scale? Is my understanding correct?
3. why integral scale generally is equal to characterized scale of the geometry? or what's meaning of integral scale?

Comment: Pretty sure neither of the authors are native English speakers either... But, what is the textbook? Is it a translation?

Comment: @hft http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/mechgrad/Frisch_Turbulence.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1.- When Frisch talks about scales he means the length of the separation, $\ell$. The displacement is not associated with the scale since it's added in both points,

$$\delta v(r+\rho,\ell)=v(r+\rho+\ell)-v(r+rho)$$

and the equality means that the quantities are independent of the displacement and the flow is statistically homogeneous. Answer: he refers only to the increments $\ell$.

2.- Local homogeneity means that the statistics of the velocity differences, $\delta v(r,\ell)$ are independent of translations ($\delta v(r+\rho,\ell)=\delta v(r,\ell)$ ) when $\ell$ is small compared to the integral scale.

3.- The integral scale is a measure of the largest scales of the system, and it's defined as the correlation length of the velocity field,

$$L=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(r) dr$$

where $f(r)$ is the (dimensionless) autocorrelation of the velocity.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect a response in the before and i just saw your answer.         for 1&2 => In fact, as far as I understand it, the definition of local homogeneity should be that the separation ℓ should be small and the  can be large. However, in terms of the modification relationship in the book, the sentence "which are small compared to the integral scale" either only modifies   or modifies both ρ and ℓ, so is the author making a mistake?      as for 3=>i know the definition of Integral scale, but i don't understand why it possess the meaning ie is a measure of largest scale of system